# 1D data frame to 2D format in R

Tags: r

My data is in a 1 column x 40000 row data frame.  I would like to make it a 200 column x 200 row data frame. When I was using all numeric values, I used the code below to transform my vector into a matrix.

```
spematrix=data.matrix(spe) 
matrix = matrix(spematrix, nrow = 200, ncol=200)
```

I cannot use this now though because my data contains non-numeric values (numbers separated by commas).

I am new to R and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome! Usually we do not put thank messages in the questions as you can read here: "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)"

Comment: +1 for Thanks. I don't think there should be a moratorium on good manners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you already know what to do. You can scrub your data with `gsub` to remove the `,` characters:

```
spe <- gsub(",","",spe[,1]) # returns a character vector 
spe <- as.numeric(spe) # convert to numeric
```

Then,

```
library(Matrix)
spematrix <- data.matrix(spe) 
matrix = Matrix(spematrix, nrow = 200, ncol=200)
```